# I want to ask few questions to nominees, should I ask them in a single question?

Tags: support, status-completed, election

I have some general questions to ask. I hope each nominee will answer. Should I ask each questions individually or in a single question to avoid too much items in case other users want to do the same (which I hope will happens) ?

I'm referring to [2011 Community Moderator Election](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1019/2011-community-moderator-election) in which Jeff suggest to ask questions to nominees on meta with the Election tag. The answer to those questions won't fit in a comment anyway.

Answer (score 3):

I think individual questions would be the way to go. If you have a lot of them, perhaps they can be grouped by some common trait and consolidated into several posts with multiple related questions in each.

Separate questions would help reduce duplication, since they'll be easier to find in case other people have similar questions they want to ask.

Comment: Anna, I'm referring to Jeff's post on the subject: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/1019/2011-community-moderator-election. Also good answers to those questions won't fit a comment box.

Comment: @Pierre: Agh. I just figured out what you were *really* asking. Sorry. Not awake yet. :)

Comment: No worries ! ;)

Comment: @Pierre: There we go. Edited to answer what you actually asked. :)