# What is the best way to ask questions to nominees?

Tags: discussion, election

Jeff [suggests](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1019/2011-community-moderator-election) that we ask questions to nominees on meta with the **Election** tag.

So far I've seen four ways to ask questions to nominees:

1. Right in the comments of nominee's introduction.
2. One question in a meta, every nominee can answer (Jeff's [suggestion](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1019/2011-community-moderator-election)).
3. Many questions in a meta post ([used](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/1950/qa-with-the-candidates-in-2011-moderator-election) on [Super User](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/1950/qa-with-the-candidates-in-2011-moderator-election) by Ivo Flipse).
4. One post on meta for many questions. Questions are asked in answers. Nominees edit the answer with their own. ([used](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1254/list-of-questions-for-candidates-in-2010-moderator-election) on [Math.SE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1254/list-of-questions-for-candidates-in-2010-moderator-election)).

I've [used method 2](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1030/nominees-2011-could-you-please-tell-more-about-your-future-moderation-style) by grouping two questions with a very similar subjects as per [Anna's suggestion](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1027/i-want-to-ask-few-questions-to-nominees-should-i-ask-them-in-a-single-question).

**What's is your preferred way?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#2 and #3 are both good choices, #4 seems like a bastardization to me, and #1 is too noisy.

Beyond that, we are also going to do "town hall" chat sessions for moderator candidates on Super User and Server Fault -- that's another option.

Comment: Can we have that town hall too Jeff?

Comment: @Pierre303, http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/1078/2011-moderator-elections-town-hall-chat

Comment: Thanks Rebacca.